# 1C-Bitrix Кастомизация фильтра элементов инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

**Есть задача:**  "Добавить фильтр при, котором пользователь заходя в свой профиль видел только свои элементы инфоблока". По сути есть группа пользователей "менеджеры" они создают в инфоблоке свои элементы, нужно что бы заходя в профиль автоматически отфильтровывались элементы других менеджеров, а оставались то те которые которые он создал. Админ соответственно видит все. Помогите пожалуйста (советом, кодом, чем угодно, с битриксом работаю недели две).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это необходимо сделать в админке? Если да, то, по сути, надо закрывать им доступ к стандартным страницам со списком элементов и разделов ИБ в админке. И создавать аналогичные страницы где добавлять ограничение в фильтр по CREATED_USER_ID или CREATED_BY.